# When should multithreading be used with asio?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-asio

I'm writing a networking library that uses Boost asio and am confused on whether I should use a separate thread to run the io_service or not.

I currently have a class that wraps all asio work. It has one io_service, one socket, etc, and uses async_read and async_write methods to communicate with the remote server. This class exposes read and write methods to allow users to communicate with the remote server.

This class is then called by other classes that use it's read/write methods to send and receive data to the remote server. In some cases there are chained calls to read/write data from the server until a final user-provided callback is called to pass on the final result of the computation.

I'm now trying to implement a connection pool and am wondering if I need a thread pool: all reads and writes to the remote server use async methods, none post-read processing involves blocking calls until the final user-provided callback. Should it not be ok to have a series of connection objects running at the same time without the need for a separate thread pool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have one thread, then when you get the data and process it, you are blocking any other calls. Of course, if the only thing that you do in a `async_read` or `async_write` is start the next async call, then the `io_service` threads is always waiting for new data to arrive, and it populates the relevant connection underlying data structures. No problem with just one thread.

But you probably have some kind of processing that interacts with the read/write data, and this is the part that you can parallelize with the thread pool. So the question is: how big is the fraction of time consumed in this processing? Is it the bottleneck (latency and bandwidth) of the server?

I saw different cases here in the past. One case was a simple server working on one list of jobs to do and dispatching the data to clients. It didn't require threading, I didn't care about the latency, as the clients would come only from time to time, and no bottleneck. Then I had another case where everything needed to be processed quickly and in this instance, I used a thread pool.

So the real question is: where is the bottleneck?

Comment: There is no blocking when reading or writing and processing received data is extremely fast, in the order of milliseconds. Does it still make sense so have a connection pool with one io_service, several connection objects and no threading?

Comment: In that case, I would say that mono-thread is enough. You may not see any performance improvement by threading this in this case (but you can try and measure, I might be wrong). And yes, always use a connection pool so that data is stored properly on each connection.

Comment: Is there a canonical rule for when to use MT or not?

Comment: No, no rule. Only measurement can hint at MT requirement, and then algorithm analysis.